# httpclient - how to set Content-Disposition to "application/json;" in a multipart

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, multipart, dotnet-httpclient

Using System.Net.Http.Httpclient, I am trying to do a multipart post in C# and with a wp8.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
varclient = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(    
"Content-Type", "application/json");

content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent(requestObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "request");
```

but using Fiddler, I noticed that I am sending this:

*Content-Disposition: form-data; name=request*

*Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8*

while I need to send this (taken from an android device where the call is working):

*Content-Disposition: application/json; name="request"*

*Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8*

- How to achieve the expected result?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it seems like you should be wanting to set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` and not the `Content-Disposition`.

Answer (score 6):

What about:

setting the header on the **HttpContent** using **TryAddWithoutValidation**

and changing the **MultipartFormDataContent** into a **MultipartContent** object:

```
var content = new MultipartContent();

var contentData = new StringContent(requestObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
contentData.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Disposition", "application/json name=request");
content.Add(contentData);
```

This results in these headers

```
POST http://www.directupload.net/index.php?mode=upload HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="6905763f-e85a-44f9-b7f4-8967b357addf"
Host: www.directupload.net
Content-Length: 274
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

--6905763f-e85a-44f9-b7f4-8967b357addf
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: application/json name=request

{    "id": 1,    "name": "A green door",    "price": 12.50,    "tags": ["home", "green"]}
--6905763f-e85a-44f9-b7f4-8967b357addf--
```

Comment: thanks but it is still the same; Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data

Comment: you change MultipartFormDataContent  to MultipartContent()?

Comment: is the request going in with the content disposition header changed but the server is now returning http 415 unsupported media type?

Comment: yes I am having 415, doing this content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Disposition", "application/json name=request");

Comment: Holy jezuz, this was a life saver. Server side was having java lang null pointer exception just due to the formatting quirk of the C# http request. After hard-formatting to the expected way, everything worked.